# String position with "," to double with "."

Tags: c#, string, xamarin, double

I am trying to convert a position  from a string to double , to use it on map.
The string position is in the format like:

```
latString: "31,92002306867021"
```

Using:

```
double lat = Convert.ToDouble(latString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

the result is wrong : **3,19200230686702E+15**

Using `Convert.ToDouble(latString)` give me number *without* `"."`

What is the right way to manage that type of convertion?

Comment: How are you determining that the result is wrong?  If the call to `Convert.ToDouble` in fact succeeded without error, _and_ you can use that primitive `double` in your calculation, then it worked, regardless of what you see on your console.

Comment: Using Convert.ToDouble(latString) give me number without "." The the position could be like 31.37893

Comment: How are you determining this?  Again, what you see from `Console.WriteLine` or maybe in your log doesn't necessarily reflect what is stored in that `double`.

Comment: I see that in Inmediate console

Comment: Where do you get your input from? Can you normalize it to using "." instead of ","? Having culture-specific input would mean you need to adjust to that culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [invariant culture is associated with the English culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.7.2) and thus uses `.` as a decimal separator. The `,` will be interpreted as a thousands separator.

If you pass in a culture that uses commas (e.g. `nl-NL`), it will work:

```
double lat = Convert.ToDouble("31,1234", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL"));
```

If you are absolutely certain the input strings can only contain valid latitudes/longitudes (i.e. numbers will never exceed 1,000), then you could also use string replacement:

```
double lat = Convert.ToDouble("31,1234".Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Explanation: +1 , but the Solution ... I am not sure if it would be better to normalize input to using "." instead.

Comment: @Fildor Will add that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have `latString` in some different culture that uses `,` as a *thousand separator* which is just *ignored* while converting to floating point:

```
  "31,92002306867021" -> 3192002306867021 -> 3.19200230686702E+15
```

First, check your *current culture*, it may well appear that it uses `,` as a *decimal separator*:

```
  string latString = "31,92002306867021";

  // Current culture
  double result = Convert.ToDouble(latString);
```

If not, you can try to *replace* `,` with a current decimal separator:

```
  string latString = "31,92002306867021";

  // be careful and culture specific: naive
  //   latString.Replace(",", ".")
  // will cause problems with some cultures 
  // (e.g. ru-Ru which uses "." as a thousand separator) 
  string value = latString.Replace(",", 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);

  double result = Convert.ToDouble(value);
```